# HTMLUnit click on angular js anchor does not open modal window

Tags: angularjs, htmlunit

A click on an angular js anchor button should open a kind of modal window (not a browser popup). However after the click I do not get the content of the new modal window.

I checked the other posts and have ensured that javascript is excecutable and I also added the wait function, but the resulting web page is the same as in the beginning - and the  `<input>` element with `name="file"` is not found.

**What do I have to change to make it work?**

This is the relevant button:

```
<a href="" ng-click="openUploadFileModal()" tooltip="Upload" tooltip-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
```

My java code:

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

            HtmlPage p = webClient.getPage(activeProject);

            Optional<HtmlAnchor> anchor = p.getAnchors().stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.getAttribute("ng-click").equals("openUploadFileModal()")).findFirst();

            anchor.ifPresent(x -> {
                HtmlPage uploadPage;
                try {
                    uploadPage = x.click();
                    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
                    System.out.println(uploadPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
                    System.out.println(uploadPage.getElementByName("file"));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });
```

On the page the following div should appear:

```
<div class="qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area" style="display: none;"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
        <div>Upload</div>
    <input multiple="multiple" name="file" type="file"></div>
    <span class="or btn-lg"> or </span>
    <span class="drag-here btn-lg">drag here</span>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>Processing dropped files...</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>
</div>
```

In Firefox it looks like this:
[image: Upload File modal dialog]